# from sets $|A| = |B|$ prove $A$ and $B$'s uncountable subsets also have same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For two uncountable sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A| = |B|$, let Z(A) denote the set of uncountable subsets of $A$.  How can we prove the cardinality of the uncountable subsets of $A$ and $B$ also equal ? that is $|Z(A)| = |Z(B)|$ ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a bijection $\phi:A\to B$, you also have a bijection $\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$. Can you find it?

Then just restrict this new bijection to $Z(A)$.

Comment: Note to the OP that not *every* bijection will work here - you need its restriction to behave appropriately - but the natural bijection *will* work.